# Django urls relation

Tags: html, django, url, django-views, django-forms

Whenever I add any '/' in front of the action parameter or after the action parameter then a '?' is always included in the URL. What is the relation between '/' and '?'.It doesn't happen with an anchor tag.

```
<form action="about">
    <button type="submit">
        hello world
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‘?’ isn't part of urls in Django, it is indicator that what follows are parameters and more specifically GET parameters.

When you submit a form using GET method (default), the browser sends the form members values in form ‘name=value’ e.g

```
 index.html?name=John&age=23
```

Hope it is clear.